# posting additional form on submit of another form

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

I have 2 forms on my webpage and in order to persist data on first form in case if 2nd one is submitted, I want to sent the 1sr form to the server too. I am using zend framekwork and if i get this 1st form on the server, I can set it as persistent data. Any idea how can I do this using jquery???

Comment: With the help of [`jquery form sumbit`] http://api.jquery.com/submit/. Refer this link..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to post two forms at same time you could to it with ajax.

Forms:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="test.php">
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
</form>
<form id="form2" method="post" action="test.php">
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit2" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#submit2').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $("#form2").attr("action"),
        data: {form1 : $("#form1").serialize(), form2 : $("#form2").serialize()},
    });
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I dont want to make an ajax request... i rather want a complete page reload in response to the request.

Comment: You can reload the page after you get respose from the server. If not make just one form from two, you can decide what data you want to grab in the backend.